# solution of initial value problem using laplace transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

> If $g(t)=0$ for $0\leq t<1$ and $g(t)=t^2-$1 for $t\geq 1$.Then find solution of initial value problem $y''+2y'+3y=g(t)$ and $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$ using Laplace transformation.

What I tried: Taking Laplace transformation on both side

$\displaystyle L(y'')+2L(y')+3L(y)=L(g(t))$

$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+2[sY(s)-y(0)]+3Y(s)=L(g(t))$

$s^2Y(s)-1+2sY(s)+3Y(s)=L(g(t))$

$$\Longrightarrow Y(s)=\frac{1+L(g(t))}{s^2+2s+3}$$

$\bullet$  If $g(t)=0$ for $0\leq t<1$. Then $L(g(t))=0$

Then $$Y(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+2s+3}=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+2}$$

$\bullet$ If $g(t)=t^2-1$. Then $\displaystyle L(g(t))=\frac{2}{s^3}-\frac{1}{s}$

Then $$Y(s)=\frac{s^3-s^2+2}{s^2(s^2+2s+3)}$$

Is my process is right. If not then please explain me How do i solve it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Jacky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did on the left side of the differential equation looks good to me but you made some mistakes on the right side. Why didn't you split the integral transform on the right side simply like this:
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\int_0^{\infty} g(t)e^{-st}dt$$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\int_0^{1} g(t)e^{-st}dt+\int_1^{\infty} g(t)e^{-st}dt$$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\int_0^{1} 0 \times e^{-st}dt+\int_1^{\infty} (t^2-1)e^{-st}du$$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\int_1^{\infty} (t^2-1)e^{-st}dt$$
Then substitute $u=t-1$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\int_0^{\infty} (u^2+2u)e^{-s(u+1)}du$$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=e^{-s}\int_0^{\infty} (u^2+2u)e^{-su}du$$
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=e^{-s}\mathcal {L}\left (u^2+2u  \right)$$
Finally:
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=e^{-s}\left (\dfrac  2{s^3}+ \dfrac 2{s^2}  \right)=\dfrac {2e^{-s}}{s^2}\left (\dfrac 1 {s}+ 1  \right)$$

---

You can also use the Heaviside step function to write $g(t)$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
g(t)&=(t^2-1)u(t-1) \\
g(t)&=((t-1+1)^2-1)u(t-1) \\
g(t)&=((t-1)^2+2(t-1))u(t-1) \\
g(t)&=(t-1)^2u(t-1)+2(t-1))u(t-1)
\end{align}
$$
Then apply the shift theorem:
$$\mathcal {L}(u(t-a)f(t-a))=e^{-as}F(s)$$
So that we have:
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=2e^{-s}\left  ( \dfrac 1 {s^3}+\dfrac 1 {s^2}   \right)$$

Comment: I cannot understand the expression before "Finally", perhaps it is incomplete? Also, why do you use sometimes $L$ and sometimes $\cal{L}$?

Comment: I should have used $\mathcal {L}$ everywhere @enzotib  I will correct that line

Comment: The line before the finally I just forgot the laplace transform since as you can see from the integral it's just $\mathcal {L} (u^2+2u)$ @enzotib

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: You're  welcome @enzotib